# Dynamic Chart on Popover Error - Cannot Acquire Context

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart js popover but I am getting the error:

*Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item*

I think that this is probably happening because the canvas tag is created dynamically, but I am not sure how to fix it. Any ideas? This is the js code I am using:

```
        $(function() {
          $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            html: true,
            content: '<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>',
          }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {

            new Chart($('#myChart'), {
              // The type of chart we want to create
              type: 'line',

              // The data for our dataset
              data: {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                datasets: [{
                  label: "My First dataset",
                  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                  borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                  data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
                }]
              },

              // Configuration options go here
              options: {}
            });
          });
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="Good vs. Evil Winrate" data-placement="bottom">Who's Winning?</button>
```

Comment: Share the HTML also. IT will help to understand the problem

Comment: I have shared the HTML too. It's on the bottom, just a simple button. Popover works, but doesn't display the chart.

Comment: maybe u should try custom popovers

Comment: @Kevin why? the popover works just fine. It's the chart that won't display because of the js error.

Comment: No I don't think. There is no errors in console. maybe the chart-js can't determine the dynamic canvas.

Comment: But I am getting a console error: "Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item". Looks like it cannot get the canvas on Chart() because it is dynamically generated. I am wondering whether there is a way to do that dynamically after the canvas element has been created.

Comment: check if u get the same error in static canvas also. 
1 more thing you can add ```settimeout()``` to delay the execution of the code after canvas get loaded.

Comment: I am not getting that error on a static canvas, because it can find the canvas. The thing is, in this case the canvas is part of the popover and is dynamically generated. I can't have it there on the page statically present.

Comment: I have just tried it again to verify, If i copy paste the canvas html outside of the popover, I am seeing the chart just fine.

Comment: thats what i am saying

Comment: Yeah, I mean i know it works statically, but I cannot use it statically in this case.

Comment: then you should try custom pop hover.. I mean ... dont rely on popover